Prove $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \log x + C + O(1/x)$ using Euler's summation formula
In Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory is a proof of $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{x} = \log x + C + O(1/x)$using Euler's summation formula, which states that if $f$ has a continuous derivative on the interval $[y,x]$, where $0 < y < x$, then $$\sum_{y < n \leq x} f(n) = \int_{y}^{x} f(t)dt + \int_{y}^{x} (t-[t])f'(t)dt + f(x)([x]-x) - f(y)([y]-y).$$ Then in our case, we take $f(t) = 1/t$. Then we plug it into the formula and get \begin{align}
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} &= \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t} - \sum_{1}^{x} \frac{t-[t]}{t^2}dt + 1 - \frac{x-[x]}{x}\\
&= \log x - \int_{1}^{x} \frac{t-[t]}{t^2}dt + 1 + O(1/x) 
\end{align}
I'm confused about how it gets $O(1/x)$ from the previous line. Any help is appreciated.

This is sloppily written as is, so -1. I think you meant $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n}$? Anyway please proofread your questions first before posting them--it is on the person asking to be clear!

$x - [x]$ is the fractional part of $x$, which between $0$ and $1$. And hence $0 \leq \frac{x - [x]}{x} < \frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{x})$.
